# Get user properties from Facebook user using Sitecore Social Connected

Tags: social-connected

I found [this article](http://www.xcentium.com/blog/2016/04/07/customizing-sitecore-social-connectors-user-creation) describing how to override the user creation pipeline processor (`sitecore/pipelines/social.matchUser`) for the Social Connected module. I have re-created this, and during debugging can see things like full name, email address and the created username.

How do I retrieve the other properties from the user's Facebook account? I have looked at the class `SelectUserPipelineArgs` (`Sitecore.Social.Connector.Pipelines.MatchUser.SelectUserPipelineArgs, Sitecore.Social`) but cannot see anything which is populated with data as I would expect.

[This question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6038/prevent-user-creation-based-on-age-using-sitecore-social-connector) is asking for a very similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/social_connected/setting_up_social_connected/setting_up/add_a_new_profile_field_to_social_connector), you have to add a new profile field mapping to the Sitecore social connected profilemapping configuration file in order to tell the Sitecore that it has to fetch it.